# php mail() set hostname on windows

Tags: php, smtp, email

Using the PHP `mail()` function is it possible to set a fully-qualified hostname for mail requests? The development environment is using Windows and using a Postfix mail server specified in php.ini using the `SMTP` directive.

The problem is PHP is not using a fully-qualified hostname and I'm getting an error message like this:

```
SMTP server response: 504 5.5.2 <pygorex1-COMPUTERNAME>: Helo command rejected: need fully-qualified hostname
```

Or perhaps this is a Postfix problem?

Comment: What is your development server's fully qualified hostname? Does it have one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mail()` itself does not, but have you considered [`ini_set()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)? You can use that to set the value for your SMTP server for just the currently executing script.